# Deleting Sql Ce system tables programmatically?

Tags: c#, sql-server-ce, microsoft-sync-framework

I`m using SQL Server Compact (SQL CE) together with sync framework. However the sync framework creates some system tables when calling the CreateSchema() method of the SqlCeClientSyncProvider (e.g. __sysSyncArticle, __sysSyncSubscription, ...).

I'm not able to delete these tables with SQL statements within Visual Studio (states that "drop table is not supported") and when trying to create a SqlCeCommand I get a message that the specified tables do not exist.

What does it take to delete SQL CE system tables programmatically?

Comment: Uhhh... I think a better question is why you're trying to delete system tables at all. Do you know what they're for? Or are you just trying to delete them because you don't like the clutter?

Comment: i have to reset the synchronization process in some special cases, delete some other tables too but want to keep some others, therefore completely deleting the database is not an option. i want to delete those system tables because i want all the metadata (last sync anchor, client id, server id, etc..) for the synchronization process being resetted.

Answer (score 1):

Joachim, You need to work with the Sync Framework on this, not against it. The point of the database is to track the sync metadata. If you want it to be a different replica (different anchor, client id, etc) then set it up as a different replica.

I suggest that you look at the new MSF 2.0, specifically the Provisioning and Management APIs. They seem to provide more of the flexibility you need.
[Sync Framework v2](http://www.microsoft.com/downloads/details.aspx?FamilyID=89adbb1e-53ff-41b5-ba17-8e43a2e66254&displaylang=en)